# How to add data to the Expandable listview with child having multiple views

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I referred this tutorial for expandable listview

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

My main activity

```
  BusActivity extends Activity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild,listDataStart,listDataEnd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);



    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild,listDataStart,listDataEnd);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    listDataStart = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    listDataEnd = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Volvo");
    listDataHeader.add("Deluxe");
    listDataHeader.add("Express");
    listDataHeader.add("Ordinary");
    // Adding child data
    List<String> volvo = new ArrayList<String>();
    volvo.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
    volvo.add("The Godfather");
    volvo.add("The Godfather: Part II");
    volvo.add("Pulp Fiction");


    List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
    nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
    nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
    nowShowing.add("Turbo");
    nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");

            List<String> now = new ArrayList<String>();
    now.add("The Conjuring");
    now.add("Despicable Me 2");
    now.add("Turbo");
    now.add("Grown Ups 2");

    List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
    comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
    comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
    comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
    comingSoon.add("The Canyons");


    List<String> comingup = new ArrayList<String>();
    comingup.add("2 Guns");
    comingup.add("The Smurfs 2");
    comingup.add("The Spectacular Now");
    comingup.add("The Canyons");


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), volvo); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), now);

    listDataStart.put(listDataHeader.get(0), nowShowing); // Header, Child data
    listDataStart.put(listDataHeader.get(1), comingup);
    );
    listDataEnd.put(listDataHeader.get(0), volvo); // Header, Child data
    listDataEnd.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);

}
```

}

My Adapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild,listStart,listEnd;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData,HashMap<String, List<String>> listStart, HashMap<String, List<String>> listEnd) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    System.out.println("Start"+listStart+"Bus"+listChildData+"End"+listEnd);
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    this.listStart=listStart;
    this.listEnd=listEnd;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    System.out.println("Child Text"+childText);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    }

    TextView txtListBus= (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.txt_busno);
    if(groupPosition==0)
    {
        //txtListBus.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FED966"));
        //txtListBus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A07900"));
    }
    else if(groupPosition==1)
    {
        txtListBus.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FED966"));
        txtListBus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A07900"));
    }
    else if(groupPosition==2)
    {
        txtListBus.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        txtListBus.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    else
    {
        txtListBus.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        txtListBus.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    }
    txtListBus.setText(childText);
    TextView txtList= (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.txt_start);
    if(groupPosition==0)
    {
        txtList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FED966"));
        txtList.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A07900"));
    }
    else if(groupPosition==1)
    {
        txtList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#64D8CD"));
        txtList.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#067B6F"));
    }
    else if(groupPosition==2)
    {
        txtList.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        txtList.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    else
    {
        txtList.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        txtList.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    txtList.setText(childText);
    TextView txt= (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.txt_end);
    if(groupPosition==0)
    {
        txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FED966"));
        txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A07900"));
    }
    else if(groupPosition==1)
    {
        txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#64D8CD"));
        txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#067B6F"));
    }
    else if(groupPosition==2)
    {
        txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    else
    {
        txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    txt.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {




    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    System.out.println("Group position"+groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.ls_head);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    if(groupPosition==0)
    {
        lblListHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD243"));
        lblListHeader.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A07900"));
    }
    else if(groupPosition==1)
    {
        lblListHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00BFAC"));
        lblListHeader.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#067B6F"));
    }
    else if(groupPosition==2)
    {
        lblListHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        lblListHeader.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    else
    {
        lblListHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        lblListHeader.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

list_item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_start"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello"
         android:gravity="right|center_vertical"

        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_busno"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_end"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_group remains same as the link

In this the child list have only a textview. I want to add an imageview and a textview to the child list. I am able to add this by changing the list_item.xml to contain the views. How can i add data to this child view that has multiple views?

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial

Add views(ImageView and TextView to your ) **list_item.xml**

Then in your **ExpandableListAdapter** 
Update below method

```
 @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

          // Get Id's of new added Text views here

          TextView myNewText= (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.new_id);
         // Get Id's of new added Image views here

           ImageView myImg= (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.new_id_img);



        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        // Set Text & Image Here

          myNewText.setText(childText);// use your desired text to display instead of 'childText'
          myImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        return convertView;
    }
```

**How to Pass Data form Activity to Adapter**

in your **prepareListData()**  method

add

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
        newList.add("2 Guns");
        newList.add("The Smurfs 2");
        newList.add("The Spectacular Now");
        newList.add("The Canyons");
        newList.add("Europa Report");
```

and at the bottom of method add this

```
 listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), newList);
```

Comment: I got this and am able to do this. How you pass data to this txtListChild and myNewText from main activity.

Comment: Can u help me with this?

Comment: At the same position of the header that is at 3 i have to insert 3 the data of the textview, imageview and the other textview. How can i do that

Comment: Elaborate your requirement

Comment: Am able to set text to only one such view the textview with the code you gave above. At the same position listDataHeader.get(3) I have a textview, an imageview and another textview. I dont kw how to set data when you have 3 child views under the same header.